# PHP yield supresses echoing in function

Tags: php, yield, php-7.1

I use PHP 7.1.15.
With following function, i try to output either that an entry is missing or yield to have a generator later on

```
public function myFunc($doc)
{
    $trans = $this->getTranslations($doc);
    foreach ($this->keys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $trans)) {
            yield $trans[$key];
        }
        echo "missing ".$key."<br>";

    }
}
```

But in my case, i get no echo - when i loop through the generator, the echo is part of it.

```
    foreach($translation as $trans){
        var_dump($trans);
    }
```

The output looks like this

```
string(33) "key1 text" 
missing key1
string(27) "key2 text"
missing key2
string(29) "key3 text" 
missing key3
```

Any Idea why this happens?

EDIT: i know, that yield doesn't act like return. It's about the echo behavior - therefore i created the output example.

Comment: Shouldn't your echo be in `else` part ? Now you will get _missing key_ message for every key in array

Comment: "In its simplest form, a yield statement looks much like a return statement, except that instead of stopping execution of the function and returning, yield instead provides a value to the code looping over the generator and **pauses** execution of the generator function"

Comment: If you want it to echo only when the key *does not exist* then you need a `else` condition.

Comment: see for the edit part... the echo should be before the output of the generator not mixed with it... the question is more about: why is the echo in the generator, and only will be outputted when looping over the generator

Answer (score 0):

At first call, the key 1 element is yielded and nothing is echoed:

```
string(33) "key1 text"
```

At the second call (2nd iteration), the generator continues where it "paused", that means it continues the next expression after the `yield`, which is the `echo` and at that moment, `$key` is still "key1", and that means it outputs:

```
missing key1
```

The end of the `foreach` loop is reached and `$key` jumps to next element and is now "key2" and the 2nd value is yielded: $trans["key2"] and the `var_dump()` shows:

```
string(27) "key2 text"
```

At next iteration, the output will be:

```
missing key2
string(29) "key3 text"
```

The 4th call to the generator will still `echo`:

```
missing key3
```

However, reaching the end of `$this->keys`, no more values are yielded, the generator reached its last value.